# How to set DataContext for a single element?

Tags: wpf, xaml

The beginner tutorial I've followed said I should create a namespace on the window,

```
<Window ... xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels" />
```

And then set the DataContext like this,

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MyViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
```

But I don't want the DataContext to apply to the whole window. I want different elements to use different contexts.

My DataGrid is defined like,

```
 <DataGrid ... DataContext="{Binding}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Queue}"
```

I guess that `DataContext="{Binding}"` bit basically uses "use parent context", but couldn't I set it to `vm:MyViewModel` right in there? I'm not sure of the proper syntax and the Visual Studio Properties window seems pretty useless in the matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like:

```
<DataGrid ... ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Queue}">
    <DataGrid.DataContext>
          <mv:MyViewModel />
    </DataGrid.DataContext>
</DataGrid>
```

This is effectively the same way you set it on a Window.

Comment: Simple enough... I think I was confusing issues. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the datacontext on the control itself.  In the case of a DataGrid you'd use

```
        <DataGrid.DataContext>
              <vm:MyViewModel />
        </DataGrid.DataContext>
```